# How to focus item in listbox from view model

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I make autocomplete and I want go throught with keys up and down in listbox with results.
Before that I have to focus the first item of listbox from textbox where I write the text.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="Client" Text="{Binding Client}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyUp] = [Action ExecuteFilterView($executionContext)]" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" >
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UserCanChooseClient}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=Clients}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
<ListBox x:Name="Clients" Width="190" Height="auto" MaxHeight="400" Margin="5 28 0 0" cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyUp] = [Action ExecuteClientsView($executionContext)]; [Event MouseLeftButtonUp]=[Action HandleClientChosenClick($eventArgs)]" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedClient}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Clients}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Code"></ListBox>
```

But the focusmanager focus the listbox, not the first item. I have to press button down twice to start to walk throught the list. Changing property SelectedClient in listbox didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

on the event SelectionChanged or other event sent by listbox:

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action LstBox_OnSelectionChanged($source, $eventArgs]"

public void LstBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var lstbox = (ListBox) sender;
        var item = (ListBoxItem)lstbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lstbox.SelectedItem);

        if (item != null)
            item.Focus();
}
```

if you want to have the first item of listbox selected at startup, you could use event Loaded:

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded] = [Action LstBox_OnLoaded($source)]"

    public void LstBox_OnLoaded(object sender)
    {
        var lstbox = (ListBox)sender;
        lstbox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        var item = (ListBoxItem)lstbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lstbox.SelectedItem);
        if (item != null)
            item.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: All logic I have in viewmodel. But I make a little workaround. I extend a Focuselement setter <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=Clients, Path=SelectedClient}" /> and in viewmodel I dynamically change SelectedClient depends on up or down keys.

Comment: you put that in viewmodel. I am using this code when i delete selectedItem and want to select the next..

Comment: you have to trap an event from listbox to use that...dont understant your problem or put more code...

Comment: Thank you. I try your solution.

Comment: sorry for my english, if i misunderstant, i have added a startup loading f you want to have the first item selected